# Setting Constant In CodeIgniter Not Working

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am setting the constant for the raw http post data in .application/config/constants.php as follows:

```
define('POST_DATA', json_decode($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"], true));
```

So I can adding sending the constant POST_DATA to the model from the controller as follows:

```
$data['data'] = $this->logins_model->signup(POST_DATA);
```

But I am getting the following error...

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message:  Use of undefined constant
>   POST_DATA - assumed 'POST_DATA'
>
> Filename:
>   controllers/logins.php

However I checked and sending the post data to the model worked when I did it like this:

```
$data['data'] = $this->logins_model->signup(json_decode($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"], true));
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Am I using the constants file incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set `constant` as an `array` . `json_deocde` produces an array, so the constant will not be set.

```
Constants may only evaluate to scalar values
```

The main point of constants is to make something that can't be altered.

But if you want to set the data then you can `serialize` the data and set to the constant and when you need that data `unserialize` the constant value

```
define('POST_DATA', serialize(json_decode($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"], true)));

$post_data     = unserialize (POST_DATA);
$data['data'] = $this->logins_model->signup($post_data);
```

Comment: What do you think I should use? The config.php file?

Comment: @StuartTheY you can set the serialized constant in application/config/constants.php

Comment: @Mischa I was adding some more notes on that on what is the alternative.

Comment: I see and what you are suggesting isn't such a good idea. Why use a constant for something that is not constant? Just store it in a variable.

Comment: @StuartTheY Glad to know you got it worked. Accept my answer if it helped you

Comment: @Mischa Using constants for something that is not a constant is not a good idea, but I was telling him the alternate if he wants to use the constants. Sorry if I was wrong on my point.

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode` returns an array or an object and PHP constants can't be arrays or objects. Only [scalar and null values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) are allowed.

The `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` will be different for every request, won't it? So, don't use constants. Just store it in a variable when you need it.